# How to synchronize thread for recursive function with sub-threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I am quite new to C++ and threading, and I got stuck in this problem for days.. It's supposed to form the base code for a fft (fast fourier transform) -- just a base code so several things are still lacking such as the twiddle terms, and inputs are double numbers (not yet complex numbers).

I want to do some parallel programming of a function **f_thread** with C++... here's a working 'compilable' code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

void get_odd_elements(std::vector<double> inpt, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inpt.size()-1; i = i + 2) {out[i/2] = inpt[i];}
}

void get_even_elements(std::vector<double> inpt, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 1; i < inpt.size(); i = i + 2) {out[i/2] = inpt[i];}
}

void attach(std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {out[i] = a[i];}
    for (int i = a.size(); i < a.size()+b.size(); i++) {out[i] = b[i];}
}

void add_vectors(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y, std::vector<double> &z) {for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {z[i] = x[i] + y[i];}}

void sub_vectors(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y, std::vector<double> &z) {for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {z[i] = y[i] - x[i];}}

//the f_thread function

void f_thread(std::vector<double> in, std::vector<double> &out) {

    if (in.size() == 1) {out = in;}
    else {

        std::vector<double> f0(in.size()/2);
        std::vector<double> f1(in.size()/2);

        get_odd_elements(in,std::ref(f0)); //get_odd_elements is a function that gets all odd-indexed elements of f
        get_even_elements(in,std::ref(f1)); //get_even_elements is a function that gets all even-indexed elements of in

        std::vector<double> a(f0.size());
        std::vector<double> b(f1.size());

        std::mutex mtx1; std::mutex mtx2;

        std::thread t0(f_thread,std::ref(f0),std::ref(a)); //create thread for f_thread on a
        std::thread t1(f_thread,std::ref(f1),std::ref(b)); //create thread for f_thread on b

        t0.join(); t1.join(); // join 2 threads

        std::vector<double> a_out(f0.size());
        std::vector<double> b_out(f1.size());

        add_vectors(std::ref(a),std::ref(b),std::ref(a_out)); //call add_vectors function : a + b
        sub_vectors(std::ref(a),std::ref(b),std::ref(b_out)); //call sub_vectors function : b - a

        std::vector<double> f_out(in.size());
        attach(a_out,b_out,std::ref(f_out)); //attach is a function that appends b to the end of a
        out = f_out; 
    }
}

int main() {
    int n_elements = 16;
    std::vector<double> sample_input(n_elements);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {sample_input[i] = i;}
    std::vector<double> output(n_elements);
    std::thread start(f_thread,std::ref(sample_input),std::ref(output));
    start.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {std::cout << "output element "; std::cout << i; std::cout << ": "; std::cout << output[i]; std::cout<< "\n";}
    }
```

So **f_thread** is initialized as a thread and then creates 2 sub-threads that recursively call **f_thread**. I tried several tricks using mutexes, but none seem to work since synchronization between the 2 sub-threads are not going wel (it's a hotspot for race conditions). Here's one code that I tried and which did not work. I also tried using global recursive mutexes but still no improvement.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

void get_odd_elements(std::vector<double> inpt, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inpt.size()-1; i = i + 2) {out[i/2] = inpt[i];}
}

void get_even_elements(std::vector<double> inpt, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 1; i < inpt.size(); i = i + 2) {out[i/2] = inpt[i];}
}

void attach(std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {out[i] = a[i];}
    for (int i = a.size(); i < a.size()+b.size(); i++) {out[i] = b[i];}
}

void add_vectors(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y, std::vector<double> &z) {for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {z[i] = x[i] + y[i];}}

void sub_vectors(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y, std::vector<double> &z) {for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {z[i] = y[i] - x[i];}}

//the f_thread function

void f_thread(std::vector<double> in, std::vector<double> &out) {

    if (in.size() == 1) {out = in;}
    else {

        std::vector<double> f0(in.size()/2);
        std::vector<double> f1(in.size()/2);

        get_odd_elements(in,std::ref(f0)); //get_odd_elements is a function that gets all odd-indexed elements of f
        get_even_elements(in,std::ref(f1)); //get_even_elements is a function that gets all even-indexed elements of in

        std::vector<double> a(f0.size());
        std::vector<double> b(f1.size());

        std::mutex mtx1; std::mutex mtx2;

        mtx1.lock(); std::thread t0(f_thread,std::ref(f0),std::ref(a)); mtx1.unlock(); //create thread for f_thread on a
        mtx2.lock(); std::thread t1(f_thread,std::ref(f1),std::ref(b)); mtx2.unlock(); //create thread for f_thread on b

        t0.join(); t1.join(); // join 2 threads

        std::vector<double> a_out(f0.size());
        std::vector<double> b_out(f1.size());

        add_vectors(std::ref(a),std::ref(b),std::ref(a_out)); //call add_vectors function : a + b
        sub_vectors(std::ref(a),std::ref(b),std::ref(b_out)); //call sub_vectors function : b - a

        std::vector<double> f_out(in.size());
        attach(a_out,b_out,std::ref(f_out)); //attach is a function that appends b to the end of a
        out = f_out; 
    }
}

int main() {
    int n_elements = 16;
    std::vector<double> sample_input(n_elements);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {sample_input[i] = i;}
    std::vector<double> output(n_elements);
    std::thread start(f_thread,std::ref(sample_input),std::ref(output));
    start.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {std::cout << "output element "; std::cout << i; std::cout << ": "; std::cout << output[i]; std::cout<< "\n";}
    }
```

I got to verify that this code compiles using g++ f_thread.cpp -pthread with standard C++ libraries in a linux (ubuntu 18.04) OS

The code now runs (no more 'aborted core dumped errors'), but the output for the threaded version changes at each run (indicating that synchronization is not working well).

For reference, here is the sequential version of the code that doesn't use sub-threads and which works well (i.e. no changes in output every time it is run)

```
// WORKING sequential version

#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

void get_odd_elements(std::vector<double> inpt, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inpt.size()-1; i = i + 2) {out[i/2] = inpt[i];}
}

void get_even_elements(std::vector<double> inpt, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 1; i < inpt.size(); i = i + 2) {out[i/2] = inpt[i];}
}

void attach(std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {out[i] = a[i];}
    for (int i = a.size(); i < a.size()+b.size(); i++) {out[i] = b[i];}
}

void add_vectors(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y, std::vector<double> &z) {for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {z[i] = x[i] + y[i];}}

void sub_vectors(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y, std::vector<double> &z) {for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {z[i] = y[i] - x[i];}}

//the f_thread function

void f_thread(std::vector<double> in, std::vector<double> &out) {

    if (in.size() == 1) {out = in;}
    else {

        std::vector<double> f0(in.size()/2);
        std::vector<double> f1(in.size()/2);

        get_odd_elements(in,std::ref(f0)); //get_odd_elements is a function that gets all odd-indexed elements of f
        get_even_elements(in,std::ref(f1)); //get_even_elements is a function that gets all even-indexed elements of in

        std::vector<double> a(f0.size());
        std::vector<double> b(f1.size());

        f_thread(std::ref(f0),std::ref(a)); // no thread, just call recursion 

        f_thread(std::ref(f1),std::ref(b)); // no thread, just call recursion 

        std::vector<double> a_out(f0.size());
        std::vector<double> b_out(f1.size());

        add_vectors(std::ref(a),std::ref(b),std::ref(a_out)); //call add_vectors function : a + b
        sub_vectors(std::ref(a),std::ref(b),std::ref(b_out)); //call sub_vectors function : b - a

        std::vector<double> f_out(in.size());
        attach(a_out,b_out,std::ref(f_out)); //attach is a function that appends b to the end of a
        out = f_out; 
    }
}

int main() {
    int n_elements = 16;
    std::vector<double> sample_input(n_elements);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {sample_input[i] = i;}
    std::vector<double> output(n_elements);
    std::thread start(f_thread,std::ref(sample_input),std::ref(output));
    start.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {std::cout << "output element "; std::cout << i; std::cout << ": "; std::cout << output[i]; std::cout<< "\n";}
    }
```

The results are supposed to be fixed to this output every time the code is run.

```
output element 0: 120
output element 1: 0
output element 2: 0
output element 3: 7.31217e-322
output element 4: 0
output element 5: 6.46188e-319
output element 6: 56
output element 7: 0
output element 8: 0
output element 9: 4.19956e-322
output element 10: 120
output element 11: 0
output element 12: 0
output element 13: 7.31217e-322
output element 14: 0
output element 15: 6.46188e-319
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and doesn't compile. Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you need the synchronization of the threads for? I'm asking because each thread is working on local copies of `f0` and `f1`, aren't they?

Comment: okay, the code is updated and verified to compile using g++ <filename.cpp> -pthread in a Ubuntu 18.04 system

Comment: i plan to use this code to solve an fft (fast fourier transform) problem that uses parallelization... i already have a sequential version exactly like the one above that works (just by removing the 2 sub-threads)

Comment: It works here because the input size is a power of 2, but note that if `in.size()/2` truncates, `get_odd_elements` will overrun its output.

Comment: It’s not part of any correctness issue, but note that repeated dynamic allocations and copies like this can easily overwhelm any advantage from parallelism.

Comment: Creating a `mutex` as a local variable that is never **shared** is pointless; taking a lock around only the *creation* of a thread (which might not even be scheduled immediately) is separately pointless.

Comment: yes, the code will not work if input is not a power of 2, but for this problem, i would like to form a base code for simple fft, so all inputs are assumed to be constrained to sizes of powers of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a threading error but out-of-bounds access to array elements in function `attach`:

```
void attach(std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b, std::vector<double> &out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {out[i] = a[i];}
    for (int i = a.size(); i < a.size()+b.size(); i++) {out[i] = b[i];}
}
```

In the second loop the index starts from `a.size()`, not from 0 - but you use it to access elements of `b` as if it started from 0.

Instead of writing loops, you could use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>`:

```
void attach(std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b, std::vector<double> &out) {
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), out.begin());
    std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), out.begin()+a.size());
}
```

After that, for recursive threading you only need this:

```
std::thread t0(f_thread,std::ref(f0),std::ref(a)); //create thread for f_thread on a
std::thread t1(f_thread,std::ref(f1),std::ref(b)); //create thread for f_thread on b
t0.join(); t1.join(); // join 2 threads
```

There is no races, since each thread works with separate input and output arrays (which you created on the stack of a "parent" thread). The result is deterministic and the same for sequential and threaded versions:

```
output element 0: 120
output element 1: 64
output element 2: 32
output element 3: 0
output element 4: 16
output element 5: 0
output element 6: 0
output element 7: 0
output element 8: 8
output element 9: 0
output element 10: 0
output element 11: 0
output element 12: 0
output element 13: 0
output element 14: 0
output element 15: 0
```

BTW you could have guessed that even your serial version is incorrect, because the input data are all integer numbers and you only copy, add and subtract those; so there is no reason for floating-point numbers like `7.31217e-322` to appear in the output.

Also please pay attention to Davis Herring`s comments: you copy the data a lot between vectors. At the very least, I would pass the vectors to functions by const references instead of by values (except if it is known that these copies are eliminated).

Finally, you should stop creating new threads much earlier than when your input arrays are of size 1. For real problem sizes, you might not be able to create thousands of threads; and even if you succeed in that, the overheads of creating and running that many threads will make your code run very very slowly. Ideally, you should not create more threads than there are HW cores on the machine where the code runs.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this by asking how many cpus there are, then splitting your work up and using a queue to join it back together.

I don't know the FFT algorithm, but from looking over your code cursorily, it looks like you basically split your data up using a finer and finer toothed comb. Except you start at the finest level and work your way up, which isn't such a great way to split things up.

You don't want a different CPU handling every other value because even on a single-chip multi-core CPU, there are multiple L1 caches. Each L1 cache is shared with at most one other core. So you want all the values a single CPU deals with to be close to each other to maximize the chance that a value you're looking for is in the cache.

So you should start your splitting with the largest contiguous chunks. Because the FFT algorithm works based on powers of two, you should count the number of cores you have. Use `thread::hardware_concurrency()` to count. Then round up to the next highest power of two and split your problem into that number of sub-FFTs. Then combined their results in the main thread.

I have a program I wrote that sort of does what you want. It [splits up a list into a number of chunks to run sort on](https://github.com/Omnifarious/parallel_sort/blob/01f56128007571c302a37040ff64bd491cd9ff6c/mysort.cpp). Then it has a queue of merges that need to be done. Each chunk is handled by a separate thread, and each merge is also spawned out into it's own thread.

I divide the number of cores in two because of a feature of modern CPUs that I'm not fond of called hyperthreading. I could've just ignored that though and it would've run fine, though since the main contention would've been over the integer ALU, it might'be been a tad slower. (Hyperthreading shares resources within a single core.)

From the other answer it sounds like your FFT code has a few bugs. I would recommend getting it to work with just one thread, then figuring out how to split it up.